# Packaging step in Dockerfile is downloading dependencies although there is a previous step to resolve dependencies

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar, dockerfile

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-12
WORKDIR /app

COPY pom.xml pom.xml
RUN mvn -B dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugins

COPY . .
RUN mvn -B package spring-boot:repackage

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","target/my-service-1.0.1.jar"]
```

I would like to download all dependencies in before the repackage step, so that I won't need to wait for depenencies to download for every code change, only for `pom.xml` changes.

However this doesn't work and the step `mvn -B package spring-boot:repackage` is always downloading packages.

My `pom.xml` is rather long, let me know if there is any relevant information there and I'll add it.

Comment: what commands are you executing to have the docker image created? are you sure its the mvn repackage goals that re-download the dependencies and not the resolve ones? You could check the contents of the maven repository in the image if everything is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to split my dependnecies step using this Dockerfile and by adding [go-offline-maven-plugin](https://github.com/qaware/go-offline-maven-plugin).

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-12
WORKDIR /app

COPY pom.xml pom.xml
RUN mvn de.qaware.maven:go-offline-maven-plugin:resolve-dependencies

RUN find /root/.m2 -type f -name '_*.repositories' -delete

COPY . .
RUN mvn -o package spring-boot:repackage

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","target/my-service-1.0.1.jar"]
```